# How to make multiple chromium profiles running at once

Tags: chrome

I would like to have separate browser for casual and work-related browsing, I would like them both to be chromium, but not share any data. How?

The result of what I want to do is simple, two icons, two terminal aliases, both different installation of application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Chrome and Chromium have inbuilt support for user profiles, with seperate settings, extensions, browser history etc. There should be a button in the top right corner of Chromium. Clicking this should allow you to create a new profile and switch between them.

[image: Screenshot of Chromium]

Image from [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Chromium_47_screenshot_showing_chrome-help.png) (User:Davod)

You can pass the profile name as a command line argument as well, so you can have shortcuts and terminal aliases for each profile. See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/377186/how-do-i-start-chrome-using-a-specified-user-profile).

Comment: I want to run both at once.

Comment: Also I don't want to have it on different basis than computer user account.

Comment: Haven't tested on GNU/Linux, but it should let you have multiple profiles open at once (does on macOS). Should be able to open the profile menu and choose the other profile and it should open in a new window. This is also completely seperate from user accounts on the computer itself.

Comment: Yes, but I want separate icons and terminal aliases for them...

Comment: See my edit to the answer or look [here](https://superuser.com/questions/377186/how-do-i-start-chrome-using-a-specified-user-profile) for how to pass the profile as a command line argument so you can set up aliases and shortcuts for the different profiles.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thank you...